# The meaning of ‘I felt obliged to him.’?

Tags: meaning

The meaning of ‘I felt obliged to him.’?

I can not understand the meaning of ‘I felt obliged to him’. I felt this sentence was weird.

Answer (score 1):

As is shown by [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/obliged)'s sense 3:

> to place under a debt of gratitude for some benefit, favor, or service:
>
> > *I'm much obliged for the ride.*

"obliged " can indicate a feeling that gratitude is owed. That is the way it is being used here.

> I felt obliged to him.

meas "I felt grateful to him." and/or "I felt that I owned him a return favor."

Answer (score 0):

It's a slightly unusual way of saying you felt you had an obligation to him. It could be as little as owing him thanks, as in "*I'm much obliged to you*" which is just a way of saying "*thank you*". Or it could mean that you thought you owed him more, either money or a favour for some service he had rendered you. In this second meaning you could also say "*I felt obligated to him*"